# Most efficient way to store this data

Tags: vb.net

I want to store data in the most efficient way the data looks like

```
 value1  SomeIntegerValues
 value2  SomeIntegerValues
 value3  SomeIntegerValues
 value4  SomeIntegerValues
 value5  SomeIntegerValues
```

For example :

```
Abhishek 45483
```

if a string matches a value then i want to get the integer value .

EDIT: im getting the above data from a website.

Comment: There is not enough context to give a reasonable answer. How many lines of data do you have? Do you need to execute searches?

Comment: @Steve lines could be ranging from 1 to 100 and yes i need to execute searches .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use a Dictionary or Map, it depends what language you're programming in.

Comment: I'll definately try Dictionary (:

Answer (score 1):

One way is to save the data in a text file, then use System.IO.File.ReadAllLines to read the file into a string array. Then do the searching and updating in memory, and write it back out using System.IO.File.WriteAllLines. You can use string Split function to separate the name from integer value in a string.

Answer (score 1):

Such an easy way .. You may save it in Database (MDB or whatever) and you may put that in two columns (ex. "key" and "value")

In your app, you can load it in two deifferent Listbox and do not sort it ..

For value searching, you can do it in First ListBox (use FindStringexact) and you can get the integer value from the second ListBox at same index ..